# Merge two sorts in one

Tags: c++, algorithm

Consider having following array (or c++ vector):

```
vector<int> a {1,3,6,5,41,8,13};
stable_sort(a.begin(), a.end(), [](int a, int b) {return a<b;});
stable_sort(a.begin(), a.end(), [](int a, int b) {return a%2 < b%2;});
```

This code first sorts vector by value, then it puts all even in first elements. The result is:

```
{e1, e2, ... en, o1, o2, ... ok}
```

where e1...en - even numbers, e1 <= e2 <= ... <= en

o1...ok odd numbers, o1 <= o2 <= ... <= ok

Question is: how do I unite these two sorts in one call of stable_sort so that the result remained the same?

```
stable_sort(a.begin(), a.end(), [](int a, int b) {/*what goes here?*/});
```

Comment: @dfri Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @dfri strict weak ordering allows the case `comp(a,b) == false && comp(b,a) == false`.

Comment: @Botje you are right, I was confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combine the two conditions with the OR operator. Make sure the second clause does not trigger when `a % 2 > b % 2`:

```
stable_sort(a.begin(), a.end(), [](int a, int b) {
  return (a % 2 < b % 2) || ((a % 2 == b % 2) && a < b);
});
```

You can make this a bit nicer by making use of the fact that tuples are sorted field by field:

```
stable_sort(a.begin(), a.end(), [](int a, int b) {
  return std::make_tuple(a % 2, a) < std::make_tuple(b % 2, b);
});
```

You no longer need the `stable_sort` now, but I left it in anyway.